# The type of <METHOD_NAME> is erroneous

Tags: java, netbeans

I am getting a strange compile error in Netbeans.

I am creating an Experiment object and calling a run method on it.

```
    Experiment experiment=new Experiment();

    Result result = experiment.run(t, steps, trials, breadth, depth, seed, distribution);
```

The compiler complains that

> The type of run(Maplayout, int, int , int, int, long, int) is
>   erroneous.

My method signature looks normal :

```
public Result run(MapLayout t, int steps, int trials, 
                        int breadth, int depth, long seed, int distribution)
```

I have double checked the paramaters I am passing in and they all seem normal. If I pass in :

```
    experiment.run(null, 1,1,1,1,1l,1);
```

I get the same compile error on the run method.

Am i missing something obvious? Has too much Javascript damaged my brain?

Comment: There's a difference in casing between the error message and the declaration, at least: Maplayout vs MapLayout. Please could you post a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: are you using netbeans 7.2?

Comment: 7.4                 ..... ..................

Comment: Is the type `Result` imported (if not in the same package) and accessible to the code that declares class `Experiment`?

Comment: there is a bug introduced in netbeans 7.2 https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=215210

Comment: ahhh figured it out. The problem was that there was a hidden compile error. The result class had a compile error in it, so it screwed up the method return.

Comment: close and reopen netbeans

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and the solution was very simple in my case.

The case:
I copy/paste some classes from another project in a package of the project i am working in.
Some of them had the old package declaration and the compiler didn't complained (for his reasons).
When i used a method with return type one of the 'wrong packaged' classes this error appeared.
(The Type of  is erroneous)

The solution
  To **solve** the issue, I changed the package declaration to be the correct one!

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem on NetBeans 8.0. It seems that if you have this structure:

`ClassA`:

```
public interface ClassA {
}
```

`ClassB`:

```
import ClassA;

public class ClassB implements ClassA {
}
```

`ClassC`:

```
import ClassB;

public class ClassC extends ClassB {
}
```

`ClassD`:

```
import ClassC;
import ClassA;

public class ClassD {
  public ClassA getClassA() {
    return new ClassC(); // error here
  }
}
```

you get this error:

```
path\to\ClassC.java:7: error: The type of new ClassC() is erroneous
        return new ClassC();
               ^
```

because `ClassC` does not explicitly implement `ClassA`, the compiler doesn't know if the type is correct. I fixed it by making `ClassC` implement `ClassA`, even though it already extends `ClassB`:

new `ClassC`:

```
import ClassA;
import ClassB;

public class ClassC extends ClassB implements ClassA {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case (Netbeans 8.0.2) restart helps

Answer (score 1):

Just do a clean and build on the project again. Most of the time this is the error specific to Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to import Result in the Experiment class.

I just had the same problem and it was because of that.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue on Netbeans 7.4. Tried to reopen IDE, clean and rebuild but does not solve. In my case, there was an `implements` clause on the erroneuos class. I removed this clause, declare it again and so the error has gone.