# The type of hasStatusCode(int) is erroneous - Netbeans 8.0.2

Tags: java, rest, netbeans, junit

I'm playing around with [REST Driver API](https://github.com/rest-driver/rest-driver) to test my Restful service.

From their github example, they have:

```
Response response = get( "http://www.example.com" );

assertThat(response, hasStatusCode(200)); // Compilation error here!
assertThat(response.asJson(), hasJsonPath("$.name", equalTo("jeff")));
```

If I place this code inside a method in my test class I get a strange compilation error from Netbeans.

The error is: `The type of hasStatusCode(int) is erroneous` (See the comment (in the code) above to where this error is shown.

I couldn't get much info about this error and the only good informations I found about it is from another SO question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22142145/the-type-of-method-name-is-erroneous).

I've restarted netbeans and the compilation error never goes away. My only hope is either it is a netbeans bug or I've imported the wrong class(es).

Here's my class code:

```
import com.github.restdriver.serverdriver.Matchers;
import static com.github.restdriver.serverdriver.RestServerDriver.get;
import static com.github.restdriver.serverdriver.RestServerDriver.header;
import com.github.restdriver.serverdriver.http.response.Response;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;


public class NewEmptyJUnitTest {

    public NewEmptyJUnitTest() { }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() { }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() { }

    @Before
    public void setUp() { }

    @After
    public void tearDown() { }

    @Test
    public void getJsonResponse() {

        Response response = get("google.com" + "/things/5", header("Accept", "application/json"));

        // Hamcrest matcher for HTTP status code
        assertThat(response, Matchers.hasStatusCode(200)); // Compilation error here -> "The type of hasStatusCode(int) is erroneous"

    }
}
```

Any help on how to solve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.

As I'm using Maven to build my project, I just pasted their (Rest Driver) Maven dependency code and I assumed everything was right.

Well, it was not, for some reason it was using the 1.1 version of `harmcrest-core` dependency instead of version 1.3

I've added version 1.3 of `harmcrest-core` as my dependency, removed the version 1.1 and it compiles just fine.